# OpenCTI for lightning - OnclickToDial

Tags: opencti, call-center

We have an integration with 3rd party Telephony System - they use the OpenCTI for lightning - and they create the softphone in their end.

They want to use the: "onClickToDial" method.

This method is listening to every click on a contact phone and return a structure of JSON payload as described in this link :

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.222.0.api_cti.meta/api_cti/sforce_api_cti_onclicktodial_lex.htm

all the returned values from this method - belong to the clicked contact.

I want to know, how can the user agent Id be sent to the telephony server from Salesforce also, to determine which agent will get the call?

I thought to tell them to use "runApex" method and to return the currently running agent user and then concatenate this to the JSON payload of the "clickToDial".

Any other methods that I can achieve this?